# Create string with backslashes for use by sed

Tags: python

I'm creating a command string in python that needs to be executed on a host using pexpect. The sed command that I wish to run on the host is as below:

```
sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\1 my_cool_option/g' /boot/bootrc
```

How can I create a variable in python that retains the backslashes as they are? Initially, I tried

```
bootrc = '/boot/bootrc'
param = 'ignorefs'
cmd = "sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\\1 {}/g' {}".format(param, bootrc)
self.runExpectCmd(cmd)
```

When I sanity-checked the above code in a python shell, it appeared quite ok:

```
>>> bootrc = '/boot/bootrc'
>>> param = 'ignorefs'
>>> cmd = "sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\\1 {}/g' {}".format(param, bootrc)
>>> print cmd
sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\1 ignorefs/g' /boot/bootrc
```

However, when I stepped through pdb to understand why the code was failing, cmd was set to

```
(Pdb) p cmd
"sed -i 's/\\(panic=30\\)/\\1 ignorefs/g' /boot/bootrc"
```

I'm at a loss at how to generate the correct string to execute the sed command.

thanks

Comment: I got the substitution to work with this: `cmd = "perl -pi -e 's/(panic=30)/\\1 foobar/g' bootrc".format(param, bootrc)` I'd still like to understand how to generate a string that sed can use.

Comment: Raw strings?  r'...'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confused me on first read of your question, but take a look at the [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) page

As you probably know, python uses the backslash character `\` as an escape character. So to include a new line in a string literal, we type

```
s = 'hello\nworld'
```

If we want an actual backslash, we use a double backslash

```
s = '\\'
```

If the character following the backslash doesn't match an escape sequence, the backslash is kept as is

```
s = '\ ' # space doesn't match any escape sequence, so you get to keep the backslash
```

This is what happens with your `\(` - you end up with `<backslash><open parnes>`

However `\1` *does* match an escape sequence - it's the literal for an octal representation of a character. So instead of `<backslash>1`, you got `<0x01>`.

When you use `p cmd` in pdb, it's printing the `repr` of the string, which happens to use backslash escaping for non-printable characters. This is different to using `print cmd` in the python shell.

```
python shell:
>>> print '\\'
\

pdb:
(Pdb) p '\\'
'\\'
```

Pdb is showing you that you have a single backslash. Similar to

```
>>> print repr('\\')
'\\'
```

So when you said

```
(Pdb) p cmd
"sed -i 's/\\(panic=30\\)/\\1 ignorefs/g' /boot/bootrc"
```

All of the double backslash pairs there *are* single backslash characters. The difference with your working example in the comments is that you have literal backslashes in front of your open/close parens.

Finally, if you don't want to worry about backslash escaping, you can use raw strings

```
>>> s = r"sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\1 my_cool_option/g' /boot/bootrc"
>>> print s
sed -i 's/\(panic=30\)/\1 my_cool_option/g' /boot/bootrc
>>> print repr(s)
"sed -i 's/\\(panic=30\\)/\\1 my_cool_option/g' /boot/bootrc"
```

Comment: Peter: Thanks for the lengthy reply, especially with explaining pdb's output. My sed command works as expected.

Comment: This doesnt work with python 3.10 now, 2024. I tried allready everything (?), no way to get a single backslash in a string

Answer (score 1):

I see that your question has been answered, but for future reference, if you have a string with backslashes and you want to be *sure* that it contains what you think it should, you can scan through it char by char and print it, eg

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

mystring = "this\nis\t a \complicated\\string"
print repr(mystring), len(mystring)
for i,v in enumerate(mystring):
    print "%2d: %-4r %02x" % (i, v, ord(v))
```

**output**

```
'this\nis\t a \\complicated\\string' 30
 0: 't'  74
 1: 'h'  68
 2: 'i'  69
 3: 's'  73
 4: '\n' 0a
 5: 'i'  69
 6: 's'  73
 7: '\t' 09
 8: ' '  20
 9: 'a'  61
10: ' '  20
11: '\\' 5c
12: 'c'  63
13: 'o'  6f
14: 'm'  6d
15: 'p'  70
16: 'l'  6c
17: 'i'  69
18: 'c'  63
19: 'a'  61
20: 't'  74
21: 'e'  65
22: 'd'  64
23: '\\' 5c
24: 's'  73
25: 't'  74
26: 'r'  72
27: 'i'  69
28: 'n'  6e
29: 'g'  67
```