# sed command run using os.system() or subprocess.call() leaves csv file without a delimiter

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, sed

I am running a Python script which takes the dump of CSVs from a Postgres database and then I want to escape double quotes in all these files. So I am using sed to do so.
In my Python code:

```
sed_for_quotes = 'sed -i s/\\"//g /home/ubuntu/PTOR/csvdata1/'+table+'.csv'  
subprocess.call(sed_for_quotes, shell=True)
```

The process completes without any error, but when I load these tables to Redshift, I get error `No delimiter found` and upon checking the CSV, I find that one of the rows is only half-loaded,for example if it is a timestamp column, then only half of it is loaded, and there is no data after that in the table (while the actual CSV has that data before running `sed`). And that leads to the `No delimiter found` error.

But when I run `sed -i s/\"//g filename.csv`on these files in the **shell** it works fine and the csv after running sed has all the rows. I have checked that there is no problem with the data in the files.

What is the reason for this not working in a Python program ? I have also tried using `sed -i.bak` in the python program but that makes no difference.

**Please Note** that I am using an extra backslash(\) in the Python code because I need to escape the other backslash.
**Other approaches tried**:

- Using `subprocess.Popen` without any buffer size and with positive buffer size, but that didn't help
- Using `subprocess.Popen(sed_for_quotes,bufsize=-4096)` (negative buffer size) worked for one of
  the files which was giving the error, but then encountered the same
  problem in another file.

Comment: Yes, the first backlash is for " and the second is for escaping the third backslash. I do print the `sed_for_quotes` to ensure that it is the same as the shell sed command I run, so it is fine.

Comment: Have you tried using raw strings?

Comment: @Merlin1896, Sorry I don't understand. I am using raw strings AFAIK.

Comment: No, you are not. Put a r in front of the string to make it a raw string: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Ok,so you mean I should change my `sed_for_quotes` string to a raw string. But will I still have to use the escape characters, like I am doing now ?

Comment: No, as written in docs I linked, the usual escape characters are not needed. Just read up on raw strings. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539279/create-string-with-backslashes-for-use-by-sed

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either

Comment: What was the returned status code?

Comment: @Yankee I've tested the code you have provided and it's working perfectly fine on my test.csv. Are you sure about not getting any errors? Maybe you're catching exceptions or something?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use intermediate shell when you do not need to. And check for return code of the subprocess to make sure it completed successfully (`check_call` does this for you)

```
path_to_file = ... # e.g. '/home/ubuntu/PTOR/csvdata1/' + table + '.csv'
subprocess.check_call(['sed', '-i', 's/"//g', path_to_file])
```

By "intermediate" shell I mean the shell process run by `subprocess` that parses the command (± splits by whitespace but not only) and runs it (runs `sed` in this example). Since you precisely know what arguments `sed` should be invoked with, you do not need all this and it's best to avoid that.

Comment: Agreed = `shell=True` is, in almost all cases, not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `sed` into a `shell script`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Parameter $1 = Filename
sed -i 's/"//g' "$1"
```

Call your `shell script` using `subprocess`:

```
sed_for_quotes = 'my_sed_script /home/ubuntu/PTOR/csvdata1/'+table+'.csv'
```

---

> Use [docs.python.org/3.6: shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)
>   shlex.split(s, comments=False, posix=True)
>       Split the string s using shell-like syntax.

Comment: I had tried that, but it doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Yankee: Updated my Answer

Comment: I tried that as well. Didn't work. I have figured out the problem though, I'll add an answer when I can confirm it works in every case. Thanks for being so helpful.