# Python - subprocess cmd as list not expanding properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any ideas why this list that I'm passing as my command to subprocess() isn't expanding properly?

```
file_name = "some_make_file"
cmd = ['gmake', '-pn', '-f', file_name, '|', 'grep', '-A1', '"^# makefile"', '|', 'grep', '-v', '"^#\|^--"', '|', 'sort', '|', 'uniq']
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = prod.communicate()
```

The output is a gmake error, and if I join the cmd to test it on the cmd line myself, I get this:

```
#join
" ".join(cmd)

#output
('gmake -pn -f some_make_file | grep -A1 "^ makefile" | grep -v '
'"^#\\|^--" | sort | uniq')
```

For the life if me, I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with this command. Any ideas? Am I not escaping something properly? Adding a special char and not realizing it?

Comment: Does the actual command run as presented? What error does your shell show when trying to execute the joined command?

Comment: The command runs as presented, that's why I tried to join the list to test what was actually being passed to subprocess.Popen(). The issue is that the list is mangling the command somehow. The output is a gmake error message.

Comment: No, the issue is that you're passing the pipe character as an argument to gmake, not creating a shell pipeline.  Either use `shell=True` or (preferably) use [`pipes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html) instead.  Or even write your shell scripts in bash or zsh instead of Python.

Comment: You are not running an intermediate shell so there is nothing to interprete the `|` as a pipe command. Even if you set `shell=True`, because you passed in a list, it will be escaped. The proper way to pipeline is given in the official python docs [Replacing Shell Pipeline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)

Comment: Try ` shlex`, read this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43808675/7414759

Comment: @Kevin and tdelaney are right, and their solutions work. Thanks - I'm somewhat new to python and am learning a ton as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running an intermediate shell so there is nothing to interprete the | as a pipe command. Even if you set shell=True, because you passed in a list, it will be escaped. The proper way to pipeline is given in the official python docs [Replacing Shell Pipeline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) – tdelaney